# Rdlc Report Grouping without repeating data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I'm replicating a report from a legacy system

the report does grouping like this

```
Name      Number    Vocation
Bob         1         Farmer
Dave        2         Farmer
                      Banker
```

Where as RDLCs do grouping like this by default

```
Name      Number    Vocation
Bob         1         Farmer
Dave        2         Farmer
Dave        2         Banker
```

Repeating the entire row, not just the "interesting bits"

is there anyway to replicate this behavior in RDLCs?

I can think of a way to fake it by massaging the data in the c# so vocation looks like this "Farmer\nBanker", but I'd like to find a better solution.

Comment: It looks like the HIdeDuplicates property is the Magic, but I'm trying to figure out what the different choices do so I can give a detailed answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hide duplicates property set to the name of your dataset solved my issue.

I had to select all the text boxes for all of the detail rows manually and change it via the properties window..

To get labels on my 2nd detail row to repeat, I changed the Hide Duplicates property on those cells only to "group", and then the labels showed up on non repeating rows only.

To get the Hide Duplicates property you need to have the Properties window open and have the row, group or cells selected.

[image: How to get to the property]