# Bottom border getting empty when i using the expression for not showing duplicate values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

When i am using the expression like

```
=IIF(Fields!feild_position.value <> Previous(Fields!field_position.value),Fields!field_position.value,"")
```

AND border style expression like

```
Default :None
Left    : Solid
Right   :empty 
Top    :=IIf((Fields!field_position.Value <> (Previous(Fields!field_position.Value))), "Solid", "None") 
Bottom  :None
```

The same expressions i used for the next 2 columns.

Can anyone suggest the how can i get the bottom border. I search in google alot still i did't find any answer related to it.

Any help must be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I must say, this is an inventive approach that almost worked for you.
You could however simply use grouping to achieve the wanted behavior.

If you add a row-group on the columns that have possible duplicate values, then the reporter should automatically merge the duplicate cells together in a row header hiding the border without needing to use expressions to hide values or borders.

You can group on *field_position* for example and let the row headings do the job for you.

I suggest you lookup some tutorials because there are many options and possibilities. Here is some information to get you started:[Controlling Row and Column Headings Report Builder and SSRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240753.aspx)

---

**Edit**:
After reading your question again, I just figured out another way to solve your problem. In my opinion, the best solution is to use grouping though.

You can define an expression for the bottom border of your cells to check if it is the final row of your dataset.

```
=Iif(COUNT(Fields!field_position.Value,"DatasetName") = RowNumber("DatasetName"), "Solid","None")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply if i use group by field_position the following duplicates row values will be empty text boxes. My requirement is to show them as combined as shown in the above image.

Comment: Like I said, you should look for some tutorials, here is a great one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251700(v=vs.90).aspx. But to get the specific thing you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16571958/4579864

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i will look into this.